# GRUB doesn't load Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8

Here what I am getting:

1. Windows loads fine only if I switch to UEFI via Boot options (<kbd>F12</kbd>).
2. I get the GRUB menu only in legacy mode.
3. In GRUB `2.02 beta2-9ubuntui1.3` menu the only selection for Windows I get is:

   ```
   Windows Recovery Environment(loader) (on /dev/sda1)
   ```

   When I select it, I get only a blinking underscore/cursor and it freezes there.

Unlike what I saw in a similar issue([Can't load Windows 8 on dual boot with Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/700855/cant-load-windows-8-on-dual-boot-with-ubuntu)), I can dual boot, but it requires me to switch back and forth from legacy and UEFI, which is inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons for GRUB not loading Windows 8.

**Reason 1:**

If your laptop supports UEFI boot and Windows, install with UEFI, then you have to create swap area + boot partition + Linux drive during installation of Ubuntu without deleting UEFI and boot partition of Windows.

Solution: if you delete the UEFI partition then you have to install both systems again for dual boot.
OR
Run windows 8 in VirtualBox. It works perfectly for me.

**Reason 2:** During installation of Ubuntu you didn't install GRUB properly.

Solution: Install GRUB again.

**Reason 3:** GRUB is not detecting Windows 8 because of damage of the UEFI or boot partition during installation

Solution: format and again installation.

Comment: Yes, I did as it was specified in Reason 1. UEFI partition is not deleted. If I switch to UEFI, it loads windows 8 directly, no GRUB menu in this case(only in legacy mode). Sounds like I can't install GRUB on its own, its a part of the Ubuntu package. It Ioads everything else, except win and it does detect windows. I am not sure though what exactly "Windows Recovery Environment(loader) (on /dev/sda1)" means. It just doesn't go there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for that is you install efi version of Ubuntu and win 8 support uefi .

For that

1. you have go to bootmanager and off UEFI boot.Select legacy boot.
2. Disable speed boot from control panel.
3. Remove Ubuntu and again install it now. Using manual partition selection.

   Search on YouTube for that: how to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS manually and you get the way.
4. now you can see win8 in grub menu.

Comment: Hi thank you. The legacy mode is on, as noted, the fast boot if off, secure boot is off as well. I do get windows selection, as noted, although, I am not 100% sure if this the way it looks like. When I select it, it just doesn't go there. If I switch to UEFI mode, its loading windows without any problems, as it was before, but no GRUB there.